# value is multiplied by two in ssrs

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, epicorerp

please can someone help the value is multiplied by two don't know why the
value must be
24.6 MT
1.2 MT

i grouped the row by part number there is only two part numbers

[image]

[image]

Comment: i updated its a field

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. The data that you've circled seems to be correct. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: bro my problem is the Quantity Field value is wrong, the value for the first row must be 22.8 MT instead of 45.6MT and the second row must be 1.2 MT Instead of 2.4 MT and i grouped by Part

Comment: What does the data coming from your dataset look like? I suspect something like a bad join that is giving you two rows instead of one. You could also add a countrows expression in the next column and see what that shows, I guess it will show twice the number you expect.

Comment: Could you add the query for retrieving this data to your question?